# How to turn on a PC from a other PC

Tags: remote-access

I have a webserver and a ftp server on my home PC and I'd like to be able to turn it on when im at school on my laptop. I figured this would be a frequent question but I can't find my answer to it on google/SO. So how would I turn on my PC from another laptop across the internet?

Comment: You might have better luck searching (and asking) for this kind of information on the superuser stackexchange site.

Comment: Sorry, didnt know about SU :)

Comment: No worries. There are a ton of stackexchange sites now, so it's kind of hard to keep track of them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

Wake-on-LAN (WOL), an ethernet computer networking standard that allows a computer to be turned on or woken up by a network message.
The message is usually sent by a program executed on another computer on the same local area network. it's an UDP message, you can easly create it from almost any language.

note that UDP messages will not pass routers...

Comment: Thanks frank, I'ma do some research.

Comment: Some (home)routers have the ability to recieve a WOL message and then send it to the internal network, but it all depends your setup.